# Least squares where $Cx$ is always equal or greater than d

Tags: least-squares

I have a $C$ (matrix $40\times 13$) and $d$ (40). When I use least squares I get $x$. But then when I do $C*x$ the result can be sometimes less than $d$. Is there a way to make sure you always get $C*x \geq d$ ?

If not, what other approach would you recommend please?

Thank you

Zdenek

Comment: Just add that constraint to your least squares problem and solve the problem using an appropriate convex optimization algorithm. You could use the CVX package to solve it easily.

Answer (score 0):

Start with 
$$
 \mathbf{A}x = b
$$
with the matrix $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and the data vector $b\in\mathbb{R}^{m}$.

The least squares solution is
$$
 x_{LS} = 
\color{blue}{\mathbf{A}^{+}b} + 
\color{red}{\left(
\mathbf{I}_{n} + \mathbf{A}^{+} \mathbf{A}
\right) y}, \qquad y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}
$$

Consider the full column rank case, the null space $\color{red}{\mathcal{N}\left( \mathbf{A}\right)}$ is trivial. The solution is unique
$$
\color{blue}{x_{LS}} = \color{blue}{\mathbf{A}^{+}b}
$$
The Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse is a matrix which projects the image of the data onto the range space $\color{blue}{\mathcal{R}\left( \mathbf{A}\right)}$. If we think of the data vector in terms of range and null space components
$$
 b = \color{blue}{b_{\mathcal{R}}} + \color{red}{b_{\mathcal{R}}},
$$
then the projection of $b$ is $\color{blue}{b_{\mathcal{R}}}$ and we have
$$
\boxed{
  \lVert \color{blue}{\mathbf{A}^{+}b} \rVert =
  \lVert \color{blue}{b_{\mathcal{R}}} \rVert 
   \le
  \lVert b \rVert 
}.
$$

The figure below shows the geometry and helps us understand that the projection of the data vector must always be less than or equal to the data vector.

[image: hyperplane]